# Tensorflow LSTM doesn't work

Tags: android, tensorflow, lstm

I've a problem with CRNN TensorFlow model when try to run it on Android (TensorFlowInferenceInterface). When I run it in Python environment everything seems to work correctly.
On Android I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected len(indices) == values.shape[0], but saw: 25 vs. 30
[[Node: shadow/LSTMLayers/stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorArrayScatter/TensorArrayScatterV3 = TensorArrayScatterV3[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@shado.../transpose"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](shadow/LSTMLayers/stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/TensorArray_1, shadow/LSTMLayers/stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/TensorArrayUnstack/range, shadow/LSTMLayers/stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/transpose, shadow/LSTMLayers/stack_bidirectional_rnn/cell_0/bidirectional_rnn/bw/bw/TensorArray_1:1)]]
at org.tensorflow.Session.run(Native Method)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

len(indices) == values.shape[0], but saw: 25 vs. 30

The program expects these two values to be the same. It does not seem like an android error. Could you verify the dimensions of your tensors and see whether they match with what you expect them to be?

Comment: I think it's Android specific problem, because the same frozen model works as a charm on desktop if I load it in Python app.